# Find the divergence of $U(x,y,z) = \frac{ayi-axj}{x^2+y^2}; a\gt0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

how would I find the divergence of the function

> $$U(x,y,z) = \frac{ayi-axj}{x^2+y^2}; a\gt0$$

would it just be this?

> $$ \nabla \times F = \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial z}$$
>
> $$=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(ay)+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(-ax)+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(0)$$
>
> $$ = 0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. $\nabla \times F$ is the notation for the curl of the vector field $F$.
2. Rewrite the vector field as $$U= \frac{ay}{x^2+y^2} i-\frac{ax}{x^2+y^2}j .$$

Comment: oh of course, put in the wrong symbol. Thank you!